# Instantly stop SFML TcpListener

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, tcp, sfml

When using an SFML `TcpListener` on the main thread, how can I immediately stop the `TcpListener::accept()` function? For instance, if I wanted to be able to receive a `SIGINT` and clean things up. To do this, I would need to be able to have the `TcpListener::accept()` function return Disconnected, or Error.

Comment: Can you close the socket out from underneath it?

Comment: @user4581301 how would I do that?

Comment: `TcpListener::close`. [Documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1TcpListener.php#ae2c83ce5a64d50b68180c46bef0a7346) says, "This function gracefully stops the listener. If the socket is not listening, this function has no effect."

Comment: @user4581301 looking over the documentation again, it seems like it should, let me see if I did something dumb.

Comment: @user4581301 nope, I have to connect to the listener so that it can accept the connection and continue execution.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen It sounds like you need the listener to be [non-blocking](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1Socket.php#details) so `accept()` doesn't wait for a client.

Comment: You also might want to take a look at [selectors](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1SocketSelector.php#a9cfda5475f17925e65889394d70af702) as a way of working timeouts and non-blocking behaviour into your code so you can call `close()` somewhere in your main event loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sean Cline for suggesting [non-blocking mode](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1Socket.php#a165fc1423e281ea2714c70303d3a9782) and [selectors](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1SocketSelector.php).

For reference, functions in SFML/Networking (I'm not sure about its other components) are blocking by default, meaning that they won't return until they completed their purpose (accepting a TCP connection, in my case). By using [non-blocking mode](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1Socket.php#a165fc1423e281ea2714c70303d3a9782), the function will return immediately, returning its status. For `TcpListener::accept()`, it will return `sf::Socket::Status::Done` if there was a connection to be accepted and it completed the task successfully. Otherwise, it might return `sf::Socket::Status::Disconnected`, or `sf::Socket::Status::NotReady`.

As for [selectors](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1SocketSelector.php), they allow you to manage several sockets on a single thread, and are especially useful for when you don't know which will send data first.